# how to run nested partials

Tags: python, partial, functools

I have a set of nested partials that I'm trying to call:

```
print(my_partial)

functools.partial(<function g at 0x000001A047370598>,
    functools.partial(<function f at 0x000001A047370620>, 
        functools.partial(<function c at 0x000001A047370400>, 5)))
```

so when I try to run my partial I get the inner partial back:

```
print(my_partial)

functools.partial(<function f at 0x000001A047370620>, 
    functools.partial(<function c at 0x000001A047370400>, 5))
```

(Or sometihng like that). Anyway, so to run this to get the final transformation on `5` (the input data), I have to do this:

```
print(my_partial()()()())

25
```

Is there a `functools` function that I can pass this nested partials to so that it'll just run it all for me? Something like this:

```
print(functools.run_partials(my_partial))

25
```

Does something like this exist? I hope so, the soltion I'm working on is buggy:

```
def run_nested(x):
    print(str(type(x())))
    if 'functools.partial' in str(type(x())):
        run_nested(x())
    print('DONE!', x())
    return x()
```

Comment: Would `my_partial = lambda: (lambda: (lambda: 25))` be an accurate example of what `my_partial` actually looks like?

Comment: You can write a loop like you've written.  Since composing functions this way isn't a normal thing to do in functional programming, I doubt there'd be built-in support for something like this.  Have you considered composing the partials so that `my_partial` is a function returning the value you want rather than a function returning a function returning a function returning a...?

Comment: Why do you have these strange objects in the first place?

Comment: If you want assistance - supply source code of your functions, not just example of their usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything in `functools` to help. You could always keep calling it until it's not callable anymore with a single `while`. Something like:

```
from functools import  partial

def f(fn):
    return fn

def g(fn):
    return fn

def c(n):
    return n*n

my_f = partial(g, partial(f, partial(c, 5) ))

print(my_f())
# functools.partial(<function f at 0x10eb7cd08>, functools.partial(<function c at 0x10eb7c598>, 5))

res = my_f
while(callable(res)):
    res = res()
print(res) # '25'
```

Comment: The `partial` you've just defined is not actually related to the OP's case. His partial is weird, where each layer is returning a brand new function when called, not merely wrapping an upper layer. Your example resolves in a single call, no matter how many times you wrap in `partial` (and in fact, your repeated wrapping on Python 3 is removed; it's identical to just doing `partial(lambda: "result")`); it's not really about `partial` here, it's about functions returning functions. That said, your solution (to loop until not callable) is legit.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger I see that now. That's a confusing nest of partials.

Comment: Yeah, that's more representative. The OP's mistake is thinking `functools.partial` is specially useful here (it isn't, it's just one way of making zero-arg functions that return functions), and your answer is a much more general solution that works with any function returning functions scenaro, not specific to `functools.partial`, which makes it much more general. Up-voted.

Answer (score 1):

```
def run_nested_partial(f):                                                  
    if isinstance(f, partial):                                              
        return f.func(                                                      
            *map(run_nested_partial, f.args),                               
            **{k: run_nested_partial(v) for k, v in f.keywords.items()}     
        )                                                                   
    return f   

                                                         
                                           
run_nested_partial(int.__add__, partial(int.__sub__, 2, 1), 3) # (2-1) + 3 = 4
```